# Material doesnt come up in texture list for UV

Tags: texturing

I'm using nodes to texture my pistol a bit, however, I've colored each material seperatly so I can assign specific parts to the pistol, however, none of them show up in the list of materials, I'm worried because I'm doing this for a game, and I'm scared that they will not show up.
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you are trying to assign materials to different parts of your object, you would need to do that in the 3D view.

Comment: @MasterHolbytla If you need someone to improve their question, please explain to them what you find confusing or what additional information it would help to have.

Comment: Yes, I already have assigned them, sorry for the confusion, I'm just scared because I have no texture file for the model right now, like, if you are texture drawing, you always have a texture file, but I don't have that.

Comment: Then you can either upload a texture or create a new one to paint on.

Comment: But how do I get the colors on the texture? The one where an arrow is pointed at

Comment: You don't, you are confusing to distinct concepts The list of the left is a list of textures, and the list on the right is a list of materials, you can't mix the two nor can you apply colors of materials in a texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the uv editor for assigning materials.  All you need to do is go into edit mode, select what you want to color, click the material you want to assign it, and click assign.

[image]

Comment: It's more that *you can't* use the uv editor for assigning materials.

Comment: True.  That's what I meant